# Longest common substring using grep

Tags: text-processing, grep, search

I have a huge text file called dictionary.txt with entries like

```
    ABC_SEQ_NUM This represents....
    ABC_RANK This represents....
    ABC_BSC_ID This represents...
    PQR_TA_DATE_AF This represents...
    XYZ_C_ID This represents...
```

In another file, I have the source for a program that is using some of these abbreviations as part of its variable names. The variable names often use the above entries as follows

```
     Facilitator.TMP_ABC_SEQ_NUM
```

So I am not able to simply search for TMP_ABC_SEQ_NUM  using grep, because it would return no match. However, the last part of the variable name ("ABC_SEQ_NUM") is actually present in the text file.

So I would like to say something like

```
      grep (longest match for) TMP_ABC_SEQ_NUM in dictionary.txt
```

So that it would return the match for

```
      ABC_SEQ_NUM
```

How to write such a command?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34466302/785213. That matches the shortest _prefix_, and would require GNU grep for its `-P` flag (Perl-compatible regular expression). I didn't try to make it work for your use case—since what _I_ needed was a prefix match—but there's at least a chance that the regexp from that solution could be adapted to your needs as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would try to match from the beginning:

```
t=TMP_ABC_SEQ_NUM
for n in $(seq 0 ${#t})
do
  grep ${t:n} dictionary.txt && break
done
```

This searches for the longest sequence, no matter where it starts:

```
for len in $(seq ${#t} -1 3)
do
   for start in $(seq 0 $((${#t}-len)))
   do
       grep ${t:start:len} dictionary.txt && break 2
   done
done
```

requirement: A bash-like shell, available here: [native win32 ports of many GNU-utils, like sh.exe, grep, sed, awk, bc, cat, tac, rev, col, cut, ...](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

A possible approach, to shorten the string from the head until it matches:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
string="TMP_ABQ_SEQ_NUM"
while ! grep "$string" dictionary.txt; do 
  # remove the shortest leading string ending with "_"
  string="${string#*_}"
done
```

Comment: Would this work under Windows? I am using grep under Windows.

Comment: @CodeBlue: it do not depends on `grep`, but on the availability of a POSIX shell. It is surely available through [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: What if the string was `FOO_ABQ_SEQ_NUM_BAR`?

Comment: @Gilles: the problem does not seem to be well defined, so mine was only a tentative solution

Answer (score 0):

Could you reverse the way you're looking at this? Rather than looking for `TMP_ABQ_SEQ_NUM` in `dictionary.txt`, could you not look for the first field for each line in `dictionary.txt` (the ABQ_SEQ_NUM) in the source file?

If this is the case, the following should work

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(awk '{print $1}' dictionary.txt) do
    grep $i $1
done
```

Pass the above script the name of the file you want to check for sequences present in dictionary.txt. Apologies if this isn't what you wanted.